# Facing "can't start new thread" error while doing multithread file operations

Tags: python, multithreading, file-io

Hey guys, I'm writing a script to update status log, this involves frequently file operations. My way of doing this is to use a "big" method including all read/write operations on this file, and set a RLock to make sure only one thread operating the file at a time.

I'm sure there is far less than 1000 threads running when I got "can't start new thread" error, so it can't be threads reaching limit, then what could be the problem causing this error? Or is there a better structure to do this job?

Thanks

Comment: [But the real question that is raised whenever somebody asks, "What's the maximum number of threads that a process can create?" is "Why are you creating so many threads that this even becomes an issue?"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/07/29/444912.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably reaching memory limit for an application on your platform. Check how much is allocated for stack for each thread.
http://docs.python.org/library/resource.html

Comment: I'm on windows, how do I check resource limit?

Comment: Try this in python: `import resource; resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_STACK)`.

Comment: There's no such module named resource on windows platform, its a Unix platform resource. Is there any other way to check this out?